# Load a local library (naoqi) to anaconda python 2 path on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, nao-robot, pepper

I loaded naoqi python SDK for pepper robot. I exracted it to `home/python/pynaoqi`. 
And than on terminal, I run `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/python/pynaoqi/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

when I type `import naoqi` on terminal it back error `No module named naoqi`

How can i added a local module into anaconda python path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you extracted it to `home/python/pynaoqi` (I'm assuming "home" is your home directory, /home/username), so that's not the path you're adding to the pythonpath - you should add `export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/username/python/pynaoqi/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

To check the python path from within python do

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Your path should be in there.